# Redux-saga dispatch more than one action with reusable generator

Tags: redux, redux-saga

I am using a reusable generator function to make the call to REQUEST/SUCCESS/FAILURE actions. I then have another generator to call that function but I would like to get some kind of feedback and raise another action. Not sure how to explain it, here is an example of what I want to do:

```
/* in actions/index.js */
export const login = {
  request: () => action(constants.LOGIN.REQUEST),
  success: (response) => {
    try {
      jwtDecode(response.auth_token);
    } catch (e) {
      return action(constants.LOGIN.FAILURE,
        { payload: { error: {
          status: 403,
          statusText: 'Invalid token',
        } } });
    }
    return action(constants.LOGIN.SUCCESS, { payload: { response } });
  },
  failure: error => action(constants.LOGIN.FAILURE, { payload: { error } }),
};

/* sagas/index.js */
function* postEntity(entity, apiFn, body) {
  yield put(entity.request());
  const { response, error } = yield apply(null, apiFn, body);
  if (response) {
    yield put(entity.success(response));
  } else {
    yield put(entity.failure(error));
  }
}

function* postLogin(action) {
  yield postEntity(login, api.login, [action.payload.email, action.payload.password]);
  // How can I get some kind of feedback (succeed or not) from postEntity here and do a put(something_else) if succeeded?
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield takeLatest(constants.LOGIN_USER, postLogin);
}
```

Any feedback is really appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have `postEntity` return a value like `response` or true/false. Then in `postLogin` check for that value.

```
const result = yield postEntity(login, api.login, [action.payload.email, action.payload.password]);
```

then check the value of `result` and fire success/failure events accordingly like you did in `postEntity`.

```
if(result) {yield put(successCreator())} else { ...}
```

Comment: Can you show me how would the `postEntity` code would return it? I tried but I can't seem to get it to return something.

Comment: Just return response

Comment: Oh, guess my problem was understanding the generators correctly. Thanks!